# In a ruby script, how to ask git to open its message editor

Tags: ruby, git, shell

I'm currently working on a command-line ruby gem that automates the "rebase + no-ff merging" workflow discussed at https://gist.github.com/jbenet/ee6c9ac48068889b0912. You can find the WIP code for this gem at https://github.com/gsmendoza/git_pretty_accept/tree/git_pretty_accept. The gem would do something like this:

```
git co master
git pull
git co pull_request
git rebase master
git co master
git merge --edit --no-ff pull_request
git push
git branch -d pull_request
git push origin:pull_request
```

When I try to run these git commands via ruby, `git merge --edit --no-ff pull_request` doesn't open the git commit message editor like I hope it would. Instead, I think git just receives a blank merge message from the editor and ruby continues with the rest of the script.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read [your code](https://github.com/gsmendoza/git_pretty_accept/commit/8be4c7a615aef5ba17369a507f9a9237591334c5#diff-bb4ffdc5d684ad72cab19743de1463beR14).

```
`git merge --no-ff --message "#{merge_message}" #{branch}`
```

In Ruby, this backtick syntax redirects the STDIN and STDOUT.

Simply try this instead:

```
system("git merge --edit --no-ff #{branch}")
```

The `system` function just forks a process and wait for the subprocess finish, without touching STDIN/STDOUT. I tested and it works.

Comment: Yeah, I tweaked the git merge call in this question. In the gem, I used the --message option. However, I would prefer to use --edit instead. Will still try using `system` instead of backticks because that was also what was recommended in this separate question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873593/open-text-editor-in-a-ruby-script). Thanks!

Comment: Edited. I have tried `--edit` before answering and it works. Just copy & paste mistake.

Comment: It does! And I thought I needed to call some IO.pipe magicky :)